# Bundle Product: Add the same bundle item twice?

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, magento-community

I have to create a simple "configurator" that should work like this:

1. The customer selects their base material
2. The customer selects their packaging material
3. The customer may enter a custom message to be printed on the product

Step 1 and 2 are very easy to do with a bundle product. I have created a simple product for each base and packaging material options and added these to the bundle product as a bundle item. So far so good.

For step 3, it is important to know that there is only a limited selection of characters available, where each character has a different price. For simplicity, let's assume that there are only two characters available:

- Character "A", with a price of 0.10$
- Character "B", with a price of 0.20$

I have also created a simple product for each character and added it as a bundle item to the bundle product. The problem with this solution is that each character can only be selected once. If the customer wanted his message to be "ABBA" they would be out of luck, as each character/bundle product option can only be selected once:

[image]

Is there a solution that allows to specify a quantity for bundle item option? So that the customer could select for example:

- 2 x "Character A"
- 3 x "Character B"

Answer (score 2):

The option types "Radio Buttons" and "Drop-down" allows to select "user defined qty" per selection. Unfortunately the option types "Checkbox" and "Multiple Select" doesn't, so you need to create one option per character with a single selection.

#### It will look like this:

```
Character A         Qty: ___
[x] None
[ ] Character A

Character B         Qty: ___
[x] None
[ ] Character B
```

You can still use JavaScript or a custom template to make it less verbose.